# How to have shortest match first when implementing mark down text styling operators in an antlr4 grammar?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, ll-grammar

I found the following (simplified) grammar on the internet as I was looking for a solution to a problem where I had to parse syntax similar to Markdown.

```
grammar Markdown;

parse    :   stat+;

stat    :   bold
        |   text
        |   WS
        ;

text    :   TEXT|SPACE;

bold    :   ('**'stat*'**');

TEXT    :   [a-zA-Z0-9]+;

SPACE   :   ' ';

WS      :   [\t\r\n]+;
```

What I want to achieve is that antlr4 kind of does a shortest match first on a sentence that looks like `**bold1** not bold **bold2**`.
This would mean that `bold1` would be bold `not bold` not, and `bold2` bold again.

However, due to antlr4 using longest match first, antlr4 parses the example as two nested bolds which is wrong.

I have already thought about multiple very complicated solutions to this problem which I actually don't want to use.
Is there a simple solution?

**UPDATE:**
Apparently I simplified the example too much.
Now here is an expanded grammar (that does not recognize markdown anymore) but which illustrates the problem I have.
It is important to note that `stat` can also be a `variable` which is just a placeholder for any keyword my language can possibly contain.

```
grammar StyleParser;

parse    :   styled_stat+;

styled_stat : italic
            | bold
            | underline
            | stat
            ;

stat    :   variable
        |   text
        ;

variable: VARIABLE;
text    :   TEXT|SPACE;

italic  :   ITALIC (stat | italic_bold | italic_underline)* ITALIC;
italic_bold: BOLD (stat | italic_bold_underline)* BOLD;
italic_bold_underline: UNDERLINE stat* UNDERLINE;

italic_underline: UNDERLINE (stat | italic_underline_bold)* UNDERLINE;
italic_underline_bold: BOLD stat* BOLD;

bold    :   BOLD (stat | bold_italic | bold_underline)* BOLD;
bold_italic: ITALIC (stat | bold_italic_underline)* ITALIC;
bold_italic_underline: UNDERLINE stat* UNDERLINE;

bold_underline: UNDERLINE (stat | bold_underline_italic)* UNDERLINE;
bold_underline_italic: ITALIC stat* ITALIC;

underline   :   UNDERLINE (stat | underline_bold | underline_italic)* UNDERLINE;   
underline_italic: ITALIC (stat | underline_italic_bold)* ITALIC;
underline_italic_bold: BOLD stat* BOLD;

underline_bold: BOLD (stat | underline_bold_italic)* BOLD;
underline_bold_italic: ITALIC stat* ITALIC; 

SPACE   :   ' ';

VARIABLE : 'VAR';
TEXT    :   [a-zA-Z0-9]+;

ITALIC: '//';
BOLD: '==';
UNDERLINE: '__';
```

With this grammar I can not nest the same style, but I can nest different styles. For example, it parses `==bold1 __underline //italic//__== not __underline__ //italic// bold ==VAR==` correctly.
The thing is that the amount of rules grows exponentially with the amount of styles you introduce, and I want to avoid this.

Comment: Why the distinction between `SPACE` and `WS`? Anyway, your problem is that your grammar does not reflect the fact that bold parts can't be nested inside each other. So the `bold` rule should not be mutually recursive with `stat`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I over-simplified the example.
Please take another look at my update.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing markdown is just non-trivial. One approach is to

1. lex the bits that are intrinsically non-ambiguous;
2. on lexer emit, evaluate the semantic context of each and adjust as appropriate;
3. parse the enhanced lexer stream, again to the extent that token sequences are intrinsically non-ambiguous;
4. tree-walk to annotate the tree or otherwise build data structures that fully describe tree-elements in markdown syntax terms.

So, for the general case of a markdown-styled `WORD`, defined as some string of text exclusive of qualifying attributes, the parser definition is

```
word
    : attrLeft* 
      w=( WORD | ENTITY | UNICODE
        | URL  | URLTAG | SPAN | HTML 
        )
      attrRight*
    ;

attrLeft  : LBOLD | LITALIC | LSTRIKE | LDQUOTE | LSQUOTE ;
attrRight : RBOLD | RITALIC | RSTRIKE | RDQUOTE | RSQUOTE ;
```

In the lexer, define all attributes as default `left` and reserve tokens for `right` attributes and `WORD`

```
tokens {
    WORD,
    RBOLD,
    RITALIC,
    RSTRIKE,
    RDQUOTE,
    RSQUOTE
}

// attributes
LBOLD   : Bold   ;
LITALIC : Italic ;
LSTRIKE : Strike ;
LDQUOTE : Quote  ;
LSQUOTE : Mark   ;

... 

// last line in the lexer
CHAR : EscChar | . ;
```

In the lexer `superclass`, override

```
public void emit(Token t) {...}
```

and decide whether

1. any particular `left` attribute should really be reassigned as a `right` attribute
2. a `CHAR` should be accumulated into a current `WORD` or should be added to a new `WORD` instance.

Now, a tree-walker can evaluate the sequences of `word`s and handle treatment of the potentially multiple overlapping, nested attributes.